# Проверка на наличие покупки в Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Не могу сообразить, как прикрутить метод в Unity.
В приложении есть кнопка с NonConsumable покупкой.
Каким методом проверить, была ли ранее когда-либо совершена покупка?
Хочу отключить кнопку, если пользователь уже ею воспользовался.
Есть конечно вариант, при нажатии записывать данные в PlayerPrefs, но что то мне подсказывает, что есть более изящное решение.

Comment: Что за платформа? Андройд?

Comment: Да, платформа - андроид

Comment: Насколько мне известно, префы можно сохранять в гугло-аккаунте, поищите, как. Я сам не в теме.